# Trying to make a slider reactive

Tags: r, shiny, ggvis

I'm trying to implement shiny and ggvis for the first time.

I want to add a simple slider to filter for mpg in the mtcars dataset.

**server.R**

```
library(shiny)
library(ggvis)
library(dplyr)

data("mtcars")


shinyServer(function(input, output){

filtercar <- reactive({

mpgs <- input$mpg

m <- mtcars %>%
  filter(
  mpg >= mpgs
  )
m <- as.data.frame(m)
})


mtcars %>%
ggvis(~mpg, ~disp, fill := "red") %>%
layer_points() %>%
bind_shiny("p", "p_ui")
})
```

**ui.R**

```
library(ggvis)
library(shiny)

shinyUI(bootstrapPage(
wellPanel(ggvisOutput("p"),
        uiOutput("p_ui"),
        HTML("Comparing cars by disp and mpg")),
wellPanel(HTML("CARS")),
wellPanel(
h4("Filter"),
sliderInput("mpg","miles per gallon", value = 20, min = 0, max = 100, step = 
1)
 )
))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

ui.R:

```
library(ggvis)
library(shiny)

shinyUI(bootstrapPage(
  wellPanel(
    uiOutput("p_ui"),
    ggvisOutput("p"),
    HTML("Comparing cars by disp and mpg")
  )))
```

server.R:

```
library(shiny)
library(ggvis)
library(dplyr)

shinyServer(function(input, output) {
  mtcars %>%
    ggvis(~mpg, ~disp) %>%
    filter(mpg > eval(input_slider(10, 35, 10))) %>%  # this is the trick
    layer_points() %>%
    scale_numeric("x", domain = c(10, 35)) %>%  # keep axis stable
    scale_numeric("y", domain = c(0, 500)) %>%  # same
    bind_shiny("p", "p_ui") 
})
```

So the trick is to use the `filter` function from `dplyr` together with `eval` and the `input_slider` function from `ggvis`.

Comment: Thank you! This got me to where I needed. Now I'm running into an issue where the program continues to crash after playing with the slider.